# Run Time Check Failure #2, AND array values swapped with outputs incorrectly

Tags: c++, arrays

I've been struggling with this piece for a while now. I've googled run time check failure and I have no idea what to do. From what I get, it's because I declared swapEven and swapOdd to have an array of size 0? I initially had this set up as a pointer array, but that just didn't work. Can anybody point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance!

```
void arrangeArrayJesseRagsdale(int* ary1, int* ary2, int arraySize1, int arraySize2) {
  int i, j;
  int temp;
  int swap = 0;
  int* swapEven = 0;
  int* swapOdd = 0;

  swapEven = new int[arraySize1];
  swapOdd = new int[arraySize2];

  cout << "  Original Arrays\n    Array #1: ";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySize1; i++) {
    cout << ary1[i] << " ";
  }

  cout << endl << "    Array #2: ";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySize2; i++) {
      cout << ary2[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < arraySize1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < arraySize2; j++) {
      if (ary1[i] % 2 != 0) {
        if (ary2[j] % 2 == 0) {
          temp = swapOdd[i] = ary1[i];
          ary1[i] = swapEven[i] = ary2[j];
          ary2[j] = temp;
          swap++;
        }
      }
      }
  }

  cout << "\n  Updated Arrays\n    Array #1: ";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySize1; i++) {
    cout << ary1[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl << "    Array #2: ";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySize2; i++) {
    cout << ary2[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  if (swap > 0) {
        cout << "\n  Swapping info -\n";
    for (i = 0; i < swap; i++) {
        cout << "    Array #1 value " << swapOdd[i] << " swapped with Array #2 value " << swapEven[i] << endl;
    }
  }

  cout << "\nThere is/are " << swap << " swap(s)." << endl << endl;

  delete[] swapEven;
  delete[] swapOdd;

  return;
}
```

Comment: `int swapEven[] = {0};  int swapOdd[] = {0};`  These arrays have 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

First, your arrays here:

```
 int swapEven[] = {0};
 int swapOdd[] = {0};
```

Have 1 element each.

Second, your loops use `arraySize1` and `arrraySize2` to index into the arrays above.  There is no check whatsoever in your code to ensure that the indexing into these arrays are within bounds.  More than likely, this is where your error occurs, and that is accessing the array out-of-bounds.

If your goal is to create arrays with the same number of elements, use `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<int> swapEven(arraySize1, 0);
std::vector<int> swapOdd(arraySize2, 0);
```

The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: gotcha. the goal is to swap odd numbers out of the first array and even numbers from the second array into the first array then state how many swaps there were; if a swap was done, then what number was swapped with which in the other array. I can't use vectors or lists.

Answer (score 0):

`swapEven` and `swapOdd` do not have zero size, they are arrays containing the single integer element, `0`. These arrays therefore have length 1.

However, from what I can tell from your code, you need to declare `swapOdd` to have at least as many elements as does `ary1`. Similarly, `swapEven` needs to have at least as many elements as does `ary2`. This is because you are storing values in those arrays using the indices of `ary1` and `ary2`. Writing to unallocated memory may cause the crash that you see.

Also use of the indices of the 2 arrays will result in non-contiguous storage of the swapped values in `swapOdd` and `swapEven`. The affect of this is that the swap reporting code will use the wrong array elements when generating the report.

You might be better off using a dynamic "list" data structure for accumulating the swapped elements. C++ has a few alternatives there such as [`list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/) and [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/) and these could be used instead of the swap arrays.

One other thing, rather than use pointer arithmetic to access the elements of arrays `ary1` and `ary2`, it's more readable to use array indexing, i.e.

```
ary[i]
```

instead of

```
*(ary1 + i)
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code but now it's saying swapOdd is being corrupted...

I can't use list or vector - this is for a class assignment.

am going to edit the code in my original posting to reflect the changes.

Comment: @JRags: that edit does not increase the size of the swap arrays, they still have length 1. You could try hardcoding a size sufficient to test the rest of your code, or use malloc to dynamically allocate memory (don't forget to free it later), or a variable sized array like this: `int swapEven[arraySize2];` for example.

Comment: mhawke - Thanks! big help! I changed it again and for the most part it works! however, sometimes it doesn't print out the correct value (such as -85023455 for example) - I'm updating the above code to reflect the changes made so far.